# inputAccessoryView not shown when editing navigation bar titleView

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, titleview

I use a simple inputaccessoryView to display next and previous buttons when a user inputs text in a couple of UITextFields. I have also added a UITextField as the titleView of the navigation bar to allow a user to set a custom title.
Everything works great, however the inputaccessoryView is not shown when editing the navigation bar's titleView, although it is there on the other textfields. The previous and next buttons work, in the sense that they jump to the titleView but then as soon as the titleView is active they disappear. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer was posted waaaay back, but I am tempted to assume that since both `UITexField`s are separate objects, they both have their own input accessory view, maybe you did set the input accessory view to be a navigation bar in your second text field, but forgot to set the `UIBarButtonItems`